# Optimizing postgres row overlap constraints involving UUIDs and GIST

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3

For various reasons all my tables have UUIDs as primary keys and I need to exclude duplicate rows where the combination of `area_id`, `user_id`, and `finished_at` <-> `started_at` window.

The only way I can see to do this involves casting UUIDs to text inside the `overlapping_allocations` constraint below. 
However this seems stupidly wasteful, am I missing a trick?

This is all running on Postgres 9.3.5 and there is freedom to enable other common extensions.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "btree_gist";

CREATE TABLE areas(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY default uuid_generate_v1(),
    name text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    -- blah blah, lots of other fields
)

CREATE TABLE allocations(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY default uuid_generate_v1(),
    area_id uuid references areas,
    user_id text NOT NULL,
    started_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    finished_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone default NOW(),
    CONSTRAINT valid_times CHECK (started_at < finished_at),
    CONSTRAINT overlapping_allocations EXCLUDE USING GIST (
        -- These two casts are horrid but GIST doesn't understand uuids
        -- see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720130/how-to-use-uuid-with-postgresql-gist-index-type
        cast("area_id" AS text) WITH =,
        user_id WITH =,
        tstzrange(started_at, COALESCE(finished_at, 'infinity'::timestamptz) ) WITH &&
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Postgres 10 the [`btree_gist` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/btree-gist.html) (in contrib) supports UUIDs, so if you add that extension first, you'll be able to create indexes and exclusion constraints without casting to text. Pre-10, casting to text is the way to go.